# Real-time Gaming with Node.js + WebSocket in Google Cloud Platform tutorial?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm a front-end developer that want to use websocket+node.js for a game in the browser.
What I'm asking for is a great tutorial on how to get that working in the Google Cloud or any other help for that matter.

What I found is this:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/real-time-gaming-with-node-js-websocket
But I'm not that familiar with the server end and is all new to the Google platform so it doesn't help me a lot.

I have a simple socket example working as long as it's in my local environment but when I deploy it I get lot's of strange errors in the console.

You can find it here
http://socket-1281.appspot.com/

There error in the console log says:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://socket-1281.appspot.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=BXTZAZbQVQYA1TBLAAAA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

So does anyone know how to solve this or where to find help?

Here's the source
https://app.box.com/s/a3ma8ivel1qj378m9nh7s9q1e3xreo7n

Comment: Well you can check the console for what the errors really are. To have a look at the complete system and then identify the errors isn't easy for sure.

Comment: I have searched for it and found that it matbe has something to do with something called nginx.

Answer (score 3):

The loadbalancer of Google App Engine doesn't support websockets. If you try to connect to socket-1281.appspot.com it will go through the loadbalancer and won't work. What you need to do is to avoid the load balancer by directly connecting to your instance.

Here is an example that might help:
https://github.com/thebergamo/appengine-websocket-nodejs#how-to-setup-the-deployment-environment

Comment: Great! Seems to be what I'm looking for. In index.html it says var host = 'your-ip'; What should I put here when I deploy it to GAE?

Comment: In the readme on that page it says: `Google App Engine -> Instances - Change the option Managed to User. Next you need set the IP to static.`. So whatever the ip is that the instance has at that point should be the one you use for your 'your-ip'.

Comment: Obrigado! That answers my second question. But will not that ip change?

Comment: It says ephemeral on the External IP of the App Engine instance.

Comment: You can promote an ephemeral external IP address to static external IP address. For more information pls visit [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-instance-ip-addresses#promote_ephemeral_ip).